# What is the wrong in my xpath?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have the following xml document:

```
<Item>
  <DataContainer>
    <ComponentId>12</ComponentId>
    <ChangeTo>undefined</ChangeTo>
    <OperationCode>ADD</OperationCode>
    <ComponentTableName>invFeatureType</ComponentTableName>
    <ComponentColName>invFeatureTypeId</ComponentColName>
    <Type>Feature</Type>
    <PlanFeatureName>Long Distance</PlanFeatureName>
    <ToPlanFeatureName/>
  </DataContainer>
</Item>
```

When I apply the following xpath to select a specific node :

```
"/Item/DataContainer[ChangeTo = '12' and Type='Feature']")
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '/ITEM/DATACONTAINER[CHANGETO = '12' AND TYPE='FEATURE']' is not a valid XPath expression

Any idea ??

Comment: add `//`  or `/` at the beginning.

Comment: I added it but it didn't solve the issue

Comment: please update your question, there is no `Collection` tag on your example, and you haven't updated it also with the recommendation. Also is it giving the same error now?

Comment: I updated my question,and it collection was written by mistake.I am still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just confused `ChangeTo` with `ComponentId`? Given *only* the document fragment you show, the following XPath expression would retrieve the single `DataContainer` element:

```
/Item/DataContainer[ComponentId = '12' and Type='Feature']
```

It is obvious that you do not show a [minimal, complete and verifiable document](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - which is always a bad idea.

Regarding the error you are getting while evaluating your path expression: If you are actually trying to evaluate a path expression that is all uppercase it will not work. XML and XPath are case-sensitive and the logical `and` cannot be uppercase in some implementations.

If not, it might be because your XPath library or framework only supports a fraction of the XPath specification. For instance, it might not support predicates (the part between `[` and `]`).

---

Reacting to a comment:

> add `//` or `/` at the beginning. – eLRuLL

No, even without `//` or `/` a path expression is valid and this will not return the kind of error you are describing.

Comment: I need ComponentId ,and it should return null if it did not match not an error.right ???

Comment: @Abadi The return values for an empty result set are implementation-specific. It seems you are using XPath with Javascript, but do not show any code whatsoever. Please tell me if you indeed used an uppercase `AND` in your path expression.